# how to allow the group of members to use an addon?

Tags: add-on

I developed a driver that handles ajax requests, super admins can use it but I want members to be able to use it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the permissions Member Groups have in the Control Panel. This includes allowing access to add-ons, and which add-ons they have access to.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/member-manager.html#member-groups

Just edit the permissions to the Member Groups you wish to allow access to your add-on.